# 400 Bad Request after sending AJAX post request in Yii 2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I want to post data via ajax to some specific controller like this :

```
<script>
    var myUrl = "<?php echo Url::to(['table/edit']); ?>";
</script>
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : myUrl,
            data: {id: userID},
            success  : function(response) {
                alert("Table is editted");
            }
        });
```

And in the controller I want to get this posted data and do some thing else.
But when I try this I am getting an error "400 (Bad Request)".
If someone can help it would be great! Thanks!

Comment: what is the code of your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add csrf like :

```
       <script>
         var myUrl = "<?php echo Url::to(['table/edit']); ?>";        
       </script>
       $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : myUrl,
            data: {id: userID,_csrf:'<?=\Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>'},
            success  : function(response) {
                alert("Table is editted");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now after adding "_csrf".

Answer (score 1):

`yii\web\BadRequestException` (represents HTTP error with code 400) can be thrown in following cases:

**1)** *Unable to verify your data submission.* CSRF validation is enabled and failed. I don't think it's the reason in your case, because it's enabled by default and included in meta tags. When using jQuery, you don't have to send it manually.

**2)** *Missing required parameters.*

If you have parameters without default values, for example:

```
public function actionTest($someParam)
{
    ...
}
```

If you didn't pass `someParam`, exception will be thrown.

**3)** *Invalid JSON data in request body.*

If you send JSON as parameter and it's not a valid JSON.

**4)** *Invalid data received for parameter.* Thrown during binding parameters to action:

```
if ($param->isArray()) {
    $args[] = $actionParams[$name] = (array) $params[$name];
} elseif (!is_array($params[$name])) {
    $args[] = $actionParams[$name] = $params[$name];
} else {
    throw new BadRequestHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Invalid data received for parameter "{param}".', [
        'param' => $name,
    ]));
}
```

Last two are rarely meet, especially the last one (can't remember even single time when I met it).

These should be all possible cases at the moment, I did global search through sources just to make sure.

Comment: I think I have the problem number 3. Do you have a simple JavaScript example?