# Yii2 and Ajax: How to send JSON object of arrays?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, yii2

I am using Yii2 framework I need to send an array containing **id of person** and an **array of id of groups** from client to server.

I got the data from a **Select2** component using **jQuery**. Then the server will response so the client can show it in a form. I mean it is not a Create or Update button of Yii2.

The client side send this json object:

```
var jsonData = {
    persons: 111,
    groups: [222, 333]
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/persons/persons?idsGroups=",
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
    }
});
```

From ther server I need to get the groups but it doens't work:

```
public function getMyGroups($groups) {
     return $groups;
}
```

My browser shows:

```
error{"readyState":4,"responseText":"Bad Request (#400): Invalid data received for parameter \"groups\".","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

But if I change the getMyGroups function to get the persons variable, it works:

```
public function getMyGroups($persons) {
     return $persons;
```

My browser shows:

```
111
```

So what this error means? I think I am sending data in a wrong way but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your client-side code isn't sending JSON. Your server-side code doesn't appear to be expecting to receive JSON. You need to change one or both of them to a format that is actually acceptable to you and both bits of code.

Comment: please show the rest of the relevant code.. with what you've posted it's not clear what's going on. how are you calling the function, etc..

Comment: Simple search on google [invalida data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803543/400-bad-request-after-sending-ajax-post-request-in-yii-2)

Comment: Hi, @Iwrestledabearonce. I am using Yii2 framework. I think the rest of the code is not important because it's part of the framework.

Comment: Hi, @Quentin. Please add your answer or explain me a bit more so I can understand my error.

Comment: Hi, @Sfili_81. Thanks for your help but the link that you shared shows how to send an object. I need to send a object with an array: {persons: 111, groups: [222, 333]}. It's complicated for me.

Comment: But your jsonData is a multidimensional Array or not? Probably i don't understand question. You send data via POST? If yes try to see data in controller with var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved in this way using this help: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
var jsonData = {
    'persons': 111,
    'groups[]': [222, 333]
};

$.post("/persons/persons", jsonData)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data loaded: " + data);
    });
```